# "mix someone up for good" : Confirmation please

Tags: word-meaning

I happened to be a *Glee* addict and finally fell upon [a girl's song.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pb3R3FoYsmc)

0:48～　She is singing "You mix me up for good right from the very start".

And I googled the phrase [mix someone up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mix-up-someone-something) and I understood to some extent,
but when she sings "mix me up for **good**", I got a bit confused.

Would that mean, "a boy" get her confused and excited ( inferring "love" ) "right from the start"? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Mix me up" could have a few different meanings in this song, but "for good" means for a long period of time, or forever.

Think of the phrase "I'm leaving for good!". Meaning that somebody is leaving and likely not coming back.

The entire lyric "You mix me up for good right from the very start" could be interpreted as *A boy is causing her long term emotional or relationship problems from their first encounter*.